# Detect internal order/created in administration

Tags: kentico

We have built a custom payment provider, see http://pmc.digital/pt/blogue/junho-2016/integracao-mb-way-com-kentico-cms/ (PT only sorry, see https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=pt&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpmc.digital%2Fpt%2Fblogue%2Fjunho-2016%2Fintegracao-mb-way-com-kentico-cms%2F for Google Translated version).

It works great, including with internal orders by site editors, however because the visitor (on the front-end) needs to be redirected to a "Pending Order Page" (with instructions to accept the payment in the provider's APP), it is also redirecting users in admin.

I was hoping to have a ViewMode for the administration, however when doing an internal order the `PortalContext.ViewMode` is live site (I guess so it can use the Shopping Cart steps/methods, etc).

Is it enough to check whether the current logged in user is not the user for the cart, and has the necessary permissions to the ecommerce module?

Considering usability what's the best method to redirect to the Orders APP from the CMSPaymentGatewayProvider ProcessPayment method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following as well:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DocumentContext.CurrentAliasPath))
{
//do front end code
}
else
{
//do back end code
}
```

I have this running in a custom payment gateway with no issues at all.

Answer (score 1):

The page that is used for creating new orders via administration interface has following url:

```
/CMSModules/Ecommerce/Pages/Tools/Orders/Order_New.aspx
```

So you can either check if the order is placing through this page or you can customize it and set some custom variable that would tell where you are placing the order.

If you want to get redirected to man Orders application, then the url is:

```
/Admin/CMSAdministration.aspx#b72ad042-31bf-4ff2-8436-25a647bba548
```

If you want just the grid of orders, then this is the url you are looking for:

```
/CMSModules/Ecommerce/Pages/Tools/Orders/Order_List.aspx
```

Comment: I prefered @Josh's answer as it was straight to the point, and quite clever, however yours completes the other bit of the question. However, is there a way to programatically get these urls? not a fan of hardcoding URL's in providers :D

Comment: Yes for the application with the GUID anchor, but not for all other formats of urls. But those GUIDs of default application should remain same across all versions of Kentico because the upgrade script relies on them.